# Where are .dex files located after apk installation?

Tags: android, path, installation, apk

After installation of apk file on android device, where exactly does the dex file get stored  or what is done with dex?

Could any one please explain how the installation happens on android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apk file is a compressed archive (actually a .zip in disguise) containing all the files needed for your program. It is stored in the data/app folder. The dex files are contained in this archive, which you can extract with any unzip tool.

Comment: I found the dex file in /data/dalvik-cache folder

Comment: An update for people reading this answer now: Since Android 5, the "dex" files in /data/dalvik-cache are actually oat files, meaning shared objects that are compiled from the app's dex file using an on-device compiler

Comment: I downloaded an app from internet which downloaded me a .zip folder, which contained .fax file, I just renamed .zip to .apk and the then it could finally be installed. Thanks for the hint btw.

Answer (score 12):

dex files are located in the /data/dalvik-cache folder.