# Where can I find a class's DEX file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dex

I'm trying to get the `.dex` of a class to run some tests ( I want to test what is demonstrated in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857807/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-a-library-at-runtime-from-an-android-applicat)).

There is supposedly an answer to my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717757/where-is-classes-dex-file), but that answer is either wrong or outdated: all of my projects' `intermediates` directories do not contain a directory called `dex`.

I am using *Android Studio 1.0.1*.

Comment: Why not use the code provided in the first link?

Comment: @JaredBurrows The code is not the problem, I need to class's code compiled as `dex`.

Answer (score 0):

### Android Studio:

**Build Type - Debug, Product Flavors - none, After running `gradlew assembleDebug`:**

```
./app/build/intermediates/dex/debug/classes.dex
```

### Android Device:

**In APK:**

See here: [Where are .dex files located after apk installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760720/where-are-dex-files-located-after-apk-installation)

**After Install:**

```
/data/dalvik-cache
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however when I build my apps I only have a single directory in `intermediates` called `dex-cache`. This directory contains a single `cache.xml` file. I don't have any directories called `dex`. Do I need to change some setting before building?

Comment: @Juicy Use your terminal/command prompt or file explorer/finder/etc, these are not shown in Android Studio.

Comment: You need to build your project. 1) `gradlew clean` 2) `gradlew assembleDebug`.

Comment: I just tried (Build -> Clean Project) and (Run -> Debug) :(

Comment: I copied and pasted `./app/build/intermediates/dex/debug/classes.dex` after running `gradlew clean && gradlew assembleDebug`. Try what my answer says.

Comment: Sorry to sound ignorant but I don't seem to have `gradlew`, a quick Google search reveals that it's a windows batch no?  When I do Build -> Clean the task bar says `Gradle executing task: clean` and  Run -> Debug in Android Studio the task bar says `Gradle executing task: AssembleDebug` which seems to be what you're suggesting.

Comment: Ah, I got the impression you were using your command prompt/terminal. Yes on Windows it is `gradlew.bat`. All I am saying is if you run the commands it will generable the APK file and the .dex file.